# Auth::login($user) in laravel not able to login the user

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I am using **laravel 5.4** and **Auth::login($user)** is showing Type error:

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must
>   implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable,
>   instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder given, called in
>   /home/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/AuthManager.php on
>   line 294

My User.php file is:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
class User extends Authenticatable
{
use Notifiable;
/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'role', 'password',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];
}
```

My AuthController.php is:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use \Hash;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
//
public function register(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required|max:30',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'regpassword' => 'required|alpha_num|confirmed'
        ]);

    /*$user = new User();
    $user['name'] = $request['name'];
    $user['email'] = $request['email'];
    $user['password'] = bcrypt($request['password']);
    $user['role'] = 'user';
    $user->save();
    */
    $user = User::create(array(
        'email' => Input::get('email'),
        'name' => Input::get('name'),
        'password' => Hash::make(Input::get('password')),
        'role' => 'user'));
    return 'success';


 }

public function userLogin(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request,[
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required' 
        ]);

    $user = User::where('email', '=', $request['email'])-> where('password' ,'=', Hash::make($request['password']))->where('role','=','user');                                                    

    if($user){
        Auth::login($user); 
        return $next($request);
    }
    else{
        return redirect()->back();
    }


}
}
```

My web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
Route::post('/register', 'AuthController@register');
Route::post('/UserLogin','AuthController@userLogin');
```

Comment: try with Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'active' => 1]);

Comment: if(Auth::attempt(....)) is not passing.

Comment: if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
            // Authentication passed...
            return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
        }else{ //do the stuff}

Comment: authentication is not passed

Comment: are you using encrypted password or just password string for attempt?

Comment: encrypted password, you can see that in register function

Comment: But I want encrypted password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved my problem as following:

```
$user = User::where('email', '=' $request['email'])->where('role','=','user')->first();
if(Hash::check($request['password'],$user->password)){
    Auth::login($user);
    return  'success';
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is this:

```
$user = User::where('email', '=', $request['email'])-> where('password' ,'=', Hash::make($request['password']))->where('role','=','user');
```

Is lacking a call to get the result set back from the query. Add `->first()`.

What it' saying is:

> You gave me an instance of the query Builder

But

> I wanted a model that extends the authenticatable class

If you open `App\User`, you'll see that it does indeed extend this class:

```
class User extends Authenticatable {
```

Comment: I added ->first() at the end. After that it does not even passes the if condition

Comment: @LakshyaGarg Then there is something wrong with the query.

Comment: i thing something is wrong with my 'password'. If i find the user only with email it returns successfullly but if i find with email and password it returns false.

Comment: I have found the solution, and updated it. Thanks for the pointing out to add ->first() to get the User model object.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
$user = User::where('email', '=', $request['email'])-> where('password' ,'=', Hash::make($request['password']))->where('role','=','user');
```

is not the way you will get the user.

Instead of

```
$user = User::where('email', '=', $request['email'])-> where('password' ,'=', Hash::make($request['password']))->where('role','=','user');                                                    

if($user){
    Auth::login($user); 
    return $next($request);
}
else{
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

you could use:

```
   $logged = auth()->attempt(
          ['email' => $request['email'], 
           'password' => $request['password'], 
           'role' => 'user']);

    if($logged) {
        return $next($request); // probably it won't work. This is fine in middleware but not in controller
    }
    else{
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

Comment: If given credentials are valid it should. But as I commented `return $next($request);` won't work in controller , you should do it somewhere else (redirect to dashboard for example)

Comment: I added return 'success'; in the if condition, but after trying to log in, it returned back to main page.

Comment: @LakshyaGarg Make sure you send valid data and you have valid role set for user.

Comment: i have checked that from database. I am using encrypted password, can it be the cause ?

Comment: @LakshyaGarg In database it should be encrypted in $request you should have obviously not encrypted password

Comment: can you clarify this comment, I didnt get you