# Try login without email or password?

Tags: laravel

I want to login as a user without email or password . try to login with column in users table called ( user_id ) , I tried this code it's find working if ( user_id ) correct , but if wrong its show me this error :

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must implement interface

So I want to show error msg if id is wrong .

My code :

```
  $user = User::where('user_id', request('user_id'))->first();

    if (auth()->login($user)) {

        return redirect('home');

    } else {
        session()->flash('error', 'Your Id Incorrect');
        return redirect('/')->withInput();
    }
```

Comment: I don't like where this is going...

Comment: @swonder pardon! don't understand what you mean!

Comment: It's irrelevant to the question but are your `user_id`'s stored as integers?

Comment: @swonder yeah it's integer(  id )  of student's each one of them has unique id , so the system required to login with this id :)

Comment: If I'm "student" with an id of 4, what's stopping me from changing the 4 to a 5. That's what I'm getting at. 

To your original question, you're missing half the error message. `Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must implement interface` which interface must in implement? What have you given it? [Maybe, this will help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43124692/authloginuser-in-laravel-not-able-to-login-the-user?rq=1).

Comment: My guess is that the user model is not implementing `Authenticatable`

Comment: @swonder The error in the linked answer is not exactly applicable; the solution for that is to make sure to use `->first()` on the query so as not to get a `Builder` instance. This question has that already. @ahmed Are you checking to see if a user was returned for the passed `user_id` before attempting a login? I.e. it won't work if you try to do `auth()->login(null);`

Comment: Here is the idea : each one of student has number contains 10 numbers in his id so just this student which has this id can login to system and these id's stored in database . got it?

Comment: <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable 
{

Comment: Sorry @TimLewis I copied the wrong link from the sidebar. [This is the one I meant to copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46362505/laravel-manual-login-function?rq=1). Since `login() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, ?????? given,` we don't know what `??????` is. So we cannot give a definitive answer. It may be null, the ID he's requesting does not exist. Without this information, it cannot be answered 100%.

Comment: @TimLewis now with this code it's working if id is correct , just want check if id not stored in database or wrong show to user the msg in else :)

Comment: @swonder Still not applicable; that error message is saying "String given", cause they're trying to call `Auth::login($userMail->email)` (that's a string, not a `User` model). I think CaddyDZ is on to the right track too. @ahmed Please post your `User.php` model. It might be missing a trait.

Comment: @TimLewis As above. Since login() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, ?????? given, we don't know what ?????? is. So we cannot give a definitive answer. It may be null, the ID he's requesting does not exist. Without this information, it cannot be answered 100%.

Comment: @swonder 0: it's working with your code thank to all of you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regards to your comment, we can check that the user with `user_id` exists first. the `first()` function returns an Eloquent Model of your given user OR null if it does not exist.

```
$user = User::where('user_id', request('user_id'))->first();


if (!is_null($user)) { // Check if the user exists before logging in.
    auth()->login($user);
    return redirect('home');

} else {
    session()->flash('error', 'Your Id Incorrect');
    return redirect('/')->withInput();
}
```

Comment: can you explain what is ( !is_null($user) ) pls ?

Comment: I'm simply using the PHP function `is_null()` to determine wether a given variable is equal to NULL. [Here is the documentation link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php) By putting an exclaimation mark in front of it like `!is_null($var)` I am checking if the variable **IS NOT** null. Since Laravel returns the eloquent model or null, it either is null or it has the model we were looking for.